# angular 5 nav-menu path query

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the Angular path query in the nav menu. Whenever I try

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params =>
            this.Name = params.get('name')
        );
```

I get undefined or null.

Full code

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    var name;

   this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params =>
        name = params.get('name')
    );

    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: returns null to alert or console

Comment: When using the exact same function it doesn't allow me to get it on the nav-menu but does on the home page, the code does work then as the alert shows the data, just the nav-menu doesn't

Comment: it uses <nav-menu></nav-menu> as the selector in the root of the app for the navigation bar

Comment: I have given all the code I am using above for the example, I actually don't have anything else to really show, after I get the info I will be putting in a more re-usable variable but that's it, just tried getting the path query at the moment nothing else

Answer (score 0):

```
this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
          return Observable.of(params);
      }).subscribe(() => {
          name = params.get('name')
});
```

Try this out!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
name=""
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
    this.name = param.get('name');
});
```

Comment: None of these seem to be working and appear to be still giving me null or undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
 public constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) {
      console.log(route.snapshot.data['name']);
  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on answers you give. Your post might be correct, but it would help even more if your explained how this works.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still looking for it. In angular 10, you can use "any". Idk if this is the only way or any better solution but it works. "any" will make angular chooses the object type that suitable for your case

```
name:any;    
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params : ParamMap) => {
      this.name = params.get('name');
    });
  }
```